# Extract multiple image links from a single div tag that has no class name

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request, python-re

Hi I have this HTML code from a website: I want to be able to extract multiple images, I have cases where there is 3-4 images. How would I go about doing that?

```
<div style="float: right;"><u>Chakra required:</u> 
     <img src="https://naruto-arena.net/images/energy/energy_2.gif">
     <img src="https://naruto-arena.net/images/energy/energy_4.gif">
</div>
```

My code:

```
 chakras1 = soup.find_all("div")[42].img['src']
 print(chakras1)
```

Result:
https://naruto-arena.net/images/energy/energy_2.gif

I only get the FIRST image but now the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract multiple images from within a tag, I personally stick to using for loops. So what I mean is once you find the div tag that you want to look within and say you call that chakras1, I would write the following:

```
    for img in chakras1.find_all("img"):
         print(img)
```

For me the steps kind of go as follows:

1. find the specific tags you are looking for (img src)
2. see what tag those tags are within (
3. navigate through the HTML to that tag (using beautiful soup's .find or .find_all functions depending on what you want to use)
4. once you have navigated to the tag search within that tag for the tags you're really looking for.

One quick note, with this method, if you are looking through multiple div tags, you're also going to need to loop through those as well.

I hope this makes sense!